# What is a more accurate algorithm I can use to calculate the sine of a number?

Tags: c, math, floating-point, trigonometry, ieee-754

I have this code that calculates a guess for sine and compares it to the standard C library's (glibc's in my case) result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double double_sin(double a)
{
    a -= (a*a*a)/6;

    return a;
}

int main(void)
{
    double clib_sin = sin(.13),
             my_sin = double_sin(.13);
    printf("%.16f\n%.16f\n%.16f\n", clib_sin, my_sin, clib_sin-my_sin);
    return 0;
}
```

The accuracy for `double_sin` is poor (about 5-6 digits). Here's my output:

```
0.1296341426196949
0.1296338333333333
0.0000003092863615
```

As you can see, after `.12963`, the results differ.

Some notes:

- I don't think the Taylor series will work for this specific situation, the factorials required for greater accuracy aren't able to be stored inside an `unsigned long long`.
- Lookup tables are not an option, they take up too much space and generally don't provide any information on how to calculate the result.
- If you use magic numbers, please explain them (although I would prefer if they were not used).
- I would greatly prefer an algorithm is easily understandable and able to be used as a reference over one that is not.
- The result does not have to be perfectly accurate. A minimum would be the requirements of IEEE 754, C, and/or POSIX.
- I'm using the IEEE-754 `double` format, which can be relied on.
- The range supported needs to be at least from `-2*M_PI` to `2*M_PI`. It would be nice if range reduction were included.

What is a more accurate algorithm I can use to calculate the sine of a number?

<s>I had an idea about something similar to Newton-Raphson, but for calculating sine instead.</s> However, I couldn't find anything on it and am ruling this possibility out.

Comment: 6-9 digits of accuracy is about all you can get out of a float in the best case. For more you need to be using double. Even then your figure's never going to be exactly the same as the `sin()` function's version because of the nature of ieee 754 floating point math.

Comment: (a) What does `unsigned long long` have to do with anything? There is no `unsigned long long` in the code. (b) What domain do you need to support? (c) What accuracy do you need?

Comment: @Shawn I tested it using `double`, same results.

Comment: The sine of x is entirely determined by the remainder of x divided by 2pi, which is a bit under 2\*\*3. You need about 100 bits of the remainder to handle cases where it happens to be very small. The largest finite `double` is around 2\*\*1024. Therefore, supporting the entire domain of `double` requires that about 1100 bits of 2pi be built into the implementation one way or another. This is usually done with a table, used during argument reduction. This conflicts with your stipulation not to use a table. Supporting the entire domain without lots of prepared data is not feasible.

Comment: (The 100-bit estimate is from memory. Finding the worst case is complicated and takes some number theory.)

Comment: IIRC, the maximum number of leading zero bits in the remainder during argument reduction for `double` is 62, so one would definitely need more than 100 bits of remainder. Achieving a faithfully-rounded implementation also requires that the remainder be expressed by a few more bits than are available in a `double`. So 120 bits for the remainder computation is probably a closer estimate.

Comment: For `double` [1144 bits](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~phatak/645/supl/Ng-ArgReduction.pdf)

Comment: "How can I decrease the error of this guess for the sine of a number?" --> important to answer this: over what range?  If say between `-2pi ... +2pi`, it is not too hard.  Over all `double`, good argument reduction to the primary range **is** hard.  Taylor series quickly fails outside primary range.

Comment: @chux I'll say over `-2pi` to `+2pi`. Isn't reasonable argument reduction possible with `fmod(x, 2*M_PI);`?

Comment: @JL2210 Not really as the _relative_ error near 2pi is huge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually get pretty close with the Taylor series.  The trick is not to calculate the full factorial on each iteration.

The Taylor series looks like this:

```
sin(x) = x^1/1! - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - x^7/7!
```

Looking at the terms, you calculate the next term by multiplying the numerator by x^2, multiplying the denominator by the next two numbers in the factorial, and switching the sign.  Then you stop when adding the next term doesn't change the result.

So you could code it like this:

```
double double_sin(double x)
{
    double result = 0;
    double factor = x;
    int i;

    for (i=2; result+factor!=result; i+=2) {
        result += factor;
        factor *= -(x*x)/(i*(i+1));
    }
    return result;
}
```

My output:

```
0.1296341426196949
0.1296341426196949
-0.0000000000000000
```

EDIT:

The accuracy can be increased further if the terms are added in the reverse direction, however this means computing a fixed number of terms:

```
#define FACTORS 30

double double_sin(double x)
{
    double result = 0;
    double factor = x;
    int i, j;
    double factors[FACTORS];

    for (i=2, j=0; j<FACTORS; i+=2, j++) {
        factors[j] = factor;
        factor *= -(x*x)/(i*(i+1));
    }
    for (j=FACTORS-1;j>=0;j--) {
        result += factors[j];
    }
    return result;
}
```

This implementation loses accuracy if `x` falls outside the range of 0 to 2*PI.  This can be fixed by calling `x = fmod(x, 2*M_PI);` at the start of the function to normalize the value.

Comment: Nice. If you print with more precision (say `%.64f`), what are the outputs?

Comment: @JL2210 They're only off by one on the last digit.  If you use `%a` to print the hex representation, you get `0x1.097da017f903cp-3` and `0x1.097da017f903dp-3`.

Comment: For `x` = 1.5707963267948965579989817342720925807952880859375 (as close as IEEE-754 binary64 gets to π/2), this routine produces 1.0000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625. Although that error may be within OP’s accuracy, it is generally considered an error for sine routines to return values outside [-1, +1], as code using sines and cosines may be written to assume all computed values are within the mathematical range of the function. Also, it takes 11 iterations with a division in each iteration, so it is not fast.

Comment: For `x` = 3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875 (as close as IEEE-754 gets to π), this routine returns a value twice the correct value, so it has a huge relative error. Also, it takes 22 iterations, so it is not fast.

Comment: For `x` = 100, this routine produces −144871497020291474280939520. The correct result is about 0.50636564110975879060561055666767060756683349609375.

Comment: @dbush Do I call `x = fmod(x, 2*M_PI);` before or after setting `factor` to `x`?

Comment: @JL2210 Do it first, that way the value is normalized before you do anything.

Comment: With suitable tweaking of the coefficients, one can have a polynomial with fewer terms, but the same precision as a truncated Taylor series.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The number you quote is indeed the closest binary64 number to pi, however if you were to check, it differs from the true value of pi in the 16th digit so it only has 15 digits of precision. The rest of the digits are wrong. And indeed, the result you got is accurate to 15 digits.

Comment: @jan: The binary64 number closest to π/2 is 1.1001001000011111101101010100010001000010110100011000 in binary. We can rewrite that as 11001001000011111101101010100010001000010110100011000•2^−52. That is 7,074,237,752,028,440 / 4,503,599,627,370,496. Then dividing as taught in elementary school would produce 1.5707963267948965579989817342720925807952880859375, but it may be easier to use some software for extended-precision arithmetic. Or we can evaluate `printf(%.99g\n", M_PI/2);` in a good C implementation with POSIX support (for `M_PI`).

Comment: @jan: Notably 1.5707963267948965579989817342720925807952880859375 **is** the binary64 number closest to π/2. Each binary64 floating-point representation represents one real number exactly. To figure out what the number is in a form you desire, such as decimal, you simply do all the arithmetic, without dropping any digits. Using `1.5707963267948965` and `1.5707963267948965579989817342720925807952880859375` in source code would produce the same binary64 value, but they are different numbers…

Comment: … In particular, any binary64 arithmetic on the number will act as if it has the value 1.5707963267948965579989817342720925807952880859375, not as if it has the value 1.5707963267948965.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You misunderstood me. What I wanted to say is that 1.5707963267948965579989817342720925807952880859375 is NOT equal to pi/2 after the 15th digit. The correct value of pi/2 to 49 decimal places is 1.5707963267948966192313216916397514420985846996875, which is a completely different number.

Comment: @jan: Whatever point you are trying to make is irrelevant. The routine was not asked to compute the sine of π/2, so that is not the desired result its behavior should be measured by. In the example I gave on 2019-09-21, I said I tested with input of 1.5707963267948965579989817342720925807952880859375. I mentioned that was as close as the IEEE-754 format (binary64) gets to π/2. That was to give readers a context for the number, not to say the routine was expected to calculate the sine of π/2. The routine was given that number and expected to compute the sine of that number,…

Comment: … and the point made in that test was not the accuracy of the result but the range. It was outside the mathematical range of sine, [−1, +1], and that is a bad property for an implementation of a sine approximation to have.